# redirect creating unwanted text in path

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an existing project that is not routing redirects as I would expect.

my redirect is like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Display", "Ladder", new { DisplayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), @id = details.CommunityId, slug = details.Slug, InnerId = activityId });
```

The url it takes me to is: http://localhost:8050/the-staples-club/communitydocuments/161/ladder-display/opq6l4et4bd7/20160429

The url is almost correct, except that a mysterious 'communitydocuments' has been inserted which causes the url to fail.  When I remove that part, it works fine.  As you can probably tell, I don't understand too much about routing, but where in the project could I investigate to stop it creating 'communitydocuments'?

edit:  In routeconfig.cs there are a couple custom routes, but nothing explaining where 'communitydocuments' is coming from.  I tried creating a custom route as follows but it still does the same thing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "LadderDisplay",
               url: "{slug}/{id}/{controller}-{action}/{innerid}/{displayDate}",
               defaults: new
               {
                   controller = "Ladder",
                   action = "Display",
                   displayDate = UrlParameter.Optional,
               }
               ,
               constraints: new
               {
                   displayDate = @"\d{8}"
               }
               );
```

Comment: can you share your routing settings from `RouteConfig.cs` ?

Comment: edited my question with comments on routeconfig.cs

Comment: maybe your `details.Slug` is `the-staples-club/communitydocuments` ?

Comment: wow now I feel a bit embarrassed because that is exactly the problem (although its to do with the id variable).  Amazing how one can spend so much time on such a simple 'problem'.  Thanks for your help.